# How to save folder from deletion via unsynced device?

Tags: google-drive

I accidentally deleted a folder in Google Drive. And it is gone. I did this via the web browser. Now, my phone was in airplane mode and is not synced yet.

> How can I use my phone to backup the folder before it is getting
>   synced and deleted?

*I have an Android smarthpone (Moto X).*

Comment: You should ask this question at [android.se].

Comment: How long ago did you delete the folder? It should still be available in your [Google Drive Trash](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/trash).

Comment: What file types are inside your folder? Does it include subfolders?